# Largest Prime Number with big numbers

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, primes

I did a Project Euler question - [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3)

I am at the end of my wits. I am getting wrong solution.
I am perplexed as to "why" particularly this code is not working.

Relevant - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279278/finding-largest-prime-number-out-of-600851475143)

This was my generated answer.

```
long long x; // The max prime factor
long long n; // The number to be factored
while (n % 2 == 0)
{
    n /= 2;
}
x = 2;
while (n % 3 == 0)
{
    n /= 3;
}
x = 3;
for (int i = 5; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2)
{
    while (n % i == 0)
    {
        n /= i;
    }
    x = i;
}
std::cout << x;
```

`n = 600851475143 answer = 6857>! I am getting x = 1471`

Comment: Unfortunately, as explained on project euler's web site, web sites like this are designed for people who are already experienced programmers, and who are looking to simply expand their skills. An experienced C++ developer will immediately recognize at least two fundamental problems with using `i <= sqrt(n)` as a loop condition, which makes the whole thing hopelessly broken. Unless someone's already an experienced C++ programmer, attempting to do one random coding puzzle after another will not accomplish anything, and nothing of value will be learned from that.

Comment: @drescherjm That will not be an issue. check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-largest-prime-factor-number/)

Comment: You always assign to `x` regardless of if a number is a factor of `n` or not.

Comment: That code still won't work if there is one big prime factor. You should only return `x` if `n` is not 1. (And please try to use more meaningful variable names.)

Comment: `i*i <= x` i much faster than `i <= sqrt(x)` or `long long a = sqrt(i);` and than `i <= a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least this for loop

```
for (int i = 5; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2)
{
    while (n % i == 0)
    {
        n /= i;
    }
    x = i;
}
```

is wrong, The variable `x` gets the value of the last i that is less than or equal to `sqrt( n )`.

Consider for example n equal to 22. After dividing it by 2 you will get n equal to 11.

After this code snippet

```
while (n % 3 == 0)
{
    n /= 3;
}
x = 3;
```

`x` will be equal to `3` and the for loop will be skipped due to its condition that evaluates to false.

The code can look for example the following way

```
    long long int n = 600851475143;

    long long int prime_factor = 0;

    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        prime_factor = 2;

        while (n % 2 == 0 ) n /= 2;
    }

    for (long long int i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            prime_factor = i;
            while (n % i == 0) n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n != 1) prime_factor = n;

    std::cout << "prime factor = " << prime_factor << '\n';
```

Also you should use the unsigned type `unsigned long long int` instead of the signed type `long long int`. Otherwise you will need to write code that will take into account the sign of the source number.

You could write a separate function as shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long max_prime_factor( unsigned long long int n )
{
    unsigned long long int prime_factor = 0;

    if (not ( n < 2 ))
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            prime_factor = 2;

            while (n % 2 == 0) n /= 2;
        }

        for (unsigned long long int i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                prime_factor = i;
                while (n % i == 0) n /= i;
            }
        }
    }

    return n < 2 ? prime_factor : n;
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " -> " << max_prime_factor( i ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 2
5 -> 5
6 -> 3
7 -> 7
8 -> 2
9 -> 3
10 -> 5
11 -> 11
12 -> 3
13 -> 13
14 -> 7
15 -> 5
16 -> 2
17 -> 17
18 -> 3
19 -> 19
```

Comment: `i <= n / i`
this was brilliant, we avoided extra library <cmath> and the computation would be simpler as well. 
Moreover, I found merging ifs and whiles would have been fine. But we have avoided the iterative assignment of prime factor. Thats cool as well.
Furthermore, I found we could have used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOKuLSKnAW4) 
Thanks Vlad.
A question at the end - This was the trial division method of prime factorization. 
What would be the fastest method to do this? (without taking an array of primes thats cheating!)

Comment: @KartikPandey I am sorry. I have not though about that yet.:)

Answer (score -3):

```
int main() {
  long long x = 0;            // The max prime factor
  long long n = 600851475143; // The number to be factored
  long long a = sqrt(n);
  while (n % 2 == 0) {
    n /= 2;
  }
  x = 2;
  while (n % 3 == 0) {
    n /= 3;
  }
  x = 3;
  for (int i = 5; i <= a; i += 2) {
    while (n % i == 0) {
      n /= i;
      x = i;
    }
  }
  
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Here it works, the sqrt(n) stoped the for loop too soon so i put it in a long long,
and the x = i; was in the wrong place

Comment: The code in general is wrong. For example try it for n equal to 5.